# Simplification of equation with matrices and inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I tested the following simplification numerically and it doesn't seem to be working:

$$ A^{-1} B^{-1} A B = I $$

Why is this invalid? Isn't the left side equivalent to $ (AB)^{-1} (AB) $?
A and B are invertible square matrices.

Comment: No, $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: You would be right if $A^{-1}B^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. But in general matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1} \ne A^{-1} B^{-1}.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! Following this, my equation actually becomes $ B^{-1} A^{-1} A B $. This does evaluate to $I$, is it not?

Comment: If by "my equation" you mean $A^{-1} B^{-1} A B$, that **does not** become $B^{-1} A^{-1} A B$ unless $A$ and $B$ happen to commute.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(AB)^{-1}=X$.

Thus, $$ABX=I$$ or
$$A^{-1}ABX=A^{-1}I$$ or
$$BX=A^{-1}$$ or
$$B^{-1}BX=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$ or
$$X=B^{-1}A^{-1},$$
which says $$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}.$$